# What does "local currency" mean on the DS-160 application form?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

I am from Egypt and currently working in the US. I am filing a DS-160 form to extend my visa. It asks for monthly salary in local currency. I am confused by the use of the word "local" - does it mean US currency or the equivalent in my home country's currency?

Comment: Local currency is not about you, but about the person processing your request. Use the currency of the embassy or authority you will submit your request to. e.g: in USD if your submitting your request to an authority in the US, EGP if you're sending it to the US embassy back in Egypt. EUR if you're sending it to the US embassy in Germany and so on

Comment: @meego that appears to be an answer to the question. Please don't use the comment section to post answers, it doesn't offer the same visibility or voting options.

Comment: Personally I would interpret it to mean the currency of the country where I reside and in which I get paid. If the two are not the same, it would mean the former.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/should-i-enter-the-salary-in-local-currency-field--1647391.html) :
Local means the currency of the consulate where you will lodge your application.
So you will want to convert the USD salary into the currency of the consulate

But another thread online says the contrary.

I would contact the consulate of your country of citizenship to confirm the exact meaning of the word

Comment: Without the second URL, it's not possible to weigh the value or authority of the two threads. And in any event, a visa application will be reviewed, and a visa issued or refused, by the consulate of the country to which the applicant wishes to travel and to which the application is submitted. That is **not** the consulate of the country of the applicant's citizenship.